# R data.table aggregate function using setdiff

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with three columns, and need to do a complex aggregation:

```r
> c
                sample     group  symbol
   1:        APPL/S Up  CBEbrown   Icosl
   2:        APPL/S Up  CBEbrown   Ampd3
   3:        APPL/S Up  CBEbrown   Thbs2
   4:        APPL/S Up  CBEbrown  Map4k4
   5:        APPL/S Up  CBEbrown Slc45a3
  ---
1724: APPL/S_BD10-2 Up TCXyellow   Nfxl1
1725: APPL/S_BD10-2 Up TCXyellow    Rhog
1726: APPL/S_BD10-2 Up TCXyellow   Wipf1
1727: APPL/S_BD10-2 Up TCXyellow Selenos
1728: APPL/S_BD10-2 Up TCXyellow  Kdelr2
```

so `sample` has two outcomes, and for each there are 7 `groups`. Basically, want the `fsetdiff` of `symbols` that are in "APPL/S_BD10-2 Up" and not "APPL/S Up":

```r
setdiff(c[group == "TCXyellow" & sample == "APPL/S_BD10-2 Up", symbol], 
        c[group == "TCXyellow" & sample == "APPL/S Up", symbol])
```

But I want to then count for each symbol, how many `group`s that `fsetdiff` occurs (from 0-7 possible). The output would look like:

```r
> out = c[, N_diff := fsetdiff(?????), by="symbol"]
> out
      symbol  N_diff
  1:   Icosl       4
  2:   Ampd3       5
  3:   Thbs2       7
  4:  Map4k4       4
  5: Slc45a3       4
 ---
503:  Unc13d       1
504:   Rpl30       1
505:    Tpt1       1
506:  Garre1       1
507: Selenos       1
```

Where `Icosl` is in "APPL/S_BD10-2 Up" and not in "APPL/S Up" for 4 of the 7 groups.

Comment: Please make the example reproducible, either with `dput()` or something like `head(dput(30))` if the whole dataset is too large.

Comment: fsetdiff was designed to take data.table on input rather than atomic vector. Did you read its manual? If count of occurrence matter, then there is `all` argument to take care of that. Anyway fsetdiff may not be the answer of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something straighforward like this:

```
f <- function(sam,sym) setdiff(sym[sam!="APPL/S UP"], sym[sam=="APPL/S UP"])

df[,.(symbol = f(sample,symbol)),group][, .(N_diff = uniqueN(group)),symbol]
```